# How can I import specific components in my Vite-based UI library?

Tags: typescript, npm, vite, tsconfig

I am working on a UI library using Vite and I'm trying to structure my imports in a specific manner. I'd prefer to use a format such as `@projectname/ui/Buttons/CertainButton` over the general `@projectname/ui`.

Initially, I attempted to use separate `index.ts` files in each component folder, leaving the `index.ts` in `src/` empty. However, this approach led to issues; Vite didn't correctly generate the library in `dist/`.

In my search for solutions, I came across the `rollup-plugin-multi-input` plugin. However, it doesn't seem to offer typescript support, which is a critical requirement for my project.

Given these challenges, I am seeking advice on the best way forward:

Is there a viable solution that will allow me to maintain the import path to a specific button, instead of just `ui/`?
Or, should I revert to using a single `index.ts` file and import as `@projectname/ui`?

I am open to any suggestions or alternatives that could help me achieve my desired import structure, keeping in mind the need for TypeScript support. I'd greatly appreciate any guidance on this issue.

[image]

How `vite.config.ts` is looking like:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsConfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
import { joinPathFragments } from "@nx/devkit";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";


export default defineConfig({
  cacheDir: "../../node_modules/.vite/ui",

  plugins: [
    dts({
      entryRoot: "src",
      tsConfigFilePath: joinPathFragments(__dirname, "tsconfig.lib.json"),
      skipDiagnostics: true
    }),
    react(),
    viteTsConfigPaths({
      root: "../../"
    }),
    svgr()
  ],

  // Uncomment this if you are using workers.
  // worker: {
  //  plugins: [
  //    viteTsConfigPaths({
  //      root: '../../',
  //    }),
  //  ],
  // },

  // Configuration for building your library.
  // See: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points.
      entry: "src/index.ts",
      name: "ui",
      fileName: "index",
      // Change this to the formats you want to support.
      // Don't forgot to update your package.json as well.
      formats: ["es", "cjs"]
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // External packages that should not be bundled into your library.
      external: ["react", "react-dom", "react/jsx-runtime"]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please share your current vite config

Comment: Why do you `Buttons/FlatButton/FlatButton.tsx` rather then `Buttons/FlatButton.tsx`?

Comment: @adsy Added vite config into question

Comment: @Dimava In my UI library, each component requires its corresponding `.stories.tsx` file, and potentially other utility files that are specific to that component. I've decided to separate each component into its own directory, hence the structure `Buttons/FlatButton/FlatButton.tsx` instead of `Buttons/FlatButton.tsx`. Actually, I thought this approach could potentially enhance the developer experience by isolating each component resources.

Comment: Generally what they do is have a structure like that for the library but reexport everything that's useful (in the case of a component library, components and a few other things are reexported), which comes with multiple benefits for the user such as a reduced number of lines of just `import ... from "..."` and an easy way to see what's useful with ctrl+space inside the {} in `import {} from "your-library"`. Nowadays you don't need to worry about isolation since if you're using modern tooling the imports will be tree-shaked so you won't have any unused code from importing.